# Disable 'end call' tone?

Tags: settings, calls, alerts

I would like to disable the "beep" that is played when I hang up.
My Android 2.3.4 phone has no option to do that in the settings.

What can I do? Do I need to upgrade my Android version, or what?

Comment: Judging by this SO [exchange](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697499/disable-end-call-tone) That is specific to the ROM, I have GB here, and do not have  Settings -> Call settings -> All calls, nor is it present on my recently upgraded ICS either.

Comment: What do you mean by ROM. Do you mean memory or a specific Android version?

Comment: @yasserbn The ROM he is referring to is the Android OS installed to the phone. An example of a ROM is CyanogenMod (cyanogenmod.com)

Comment: If there's no option, you cannot do anything except trying to locate the tone's .ogg file and delete it, however this is a modification of the firmware (ROM) and comes with a risk. You also need to root your phone first to be able to alter the firmware.

Answer (score 2):

For those who may encounter this in the future (trying to rip this tone perhaps?)
apparently, this tone is not saved locally as a file but rather appears to be [generated on the fly](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ToneGenerator#TONE_PROP_PROMPT) by android:[image]

Answer (score 1):

While weird as to why do you hear that sound, you can look for it with a free APP:

[Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.explorer) by Speed Software available from Google Play Store:

1. Download and Install the APP
2. Open an browser your system to:

   /system/media/audio/ui
3. Listen each file there to identify the one that corresponds to the sound you hear

   If you are able to identify it, you can then buy the [Root Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer&hl=en) by Speed Software available from Google Play Store. (3.59€).

   With this version you can delete files, thus deleting that audio file or replace it with an empty one to avoid issues with the system, but remove the sound anyway.

Comment: I did not find the file. Are you sure it should be there?

Comment: @yasserbn That is the location of the system UI sounds, like keypress, clicks, etc. That's the most probable location for that sound you've mentioned gets stored at.

Comment: @yasserbn You can check the remaining folders inside `/system/media/audio/` for that sound! Despite being a bit strange not having a sound of that nature at the `ui` folder.